# replacing null values in a Pandas Dataframe using applymap

Tags: python, pandas

I've got an "Age" column, but sometimes NaN values are displayed. 
I know I can use "fillna" for this purposes but I've tried to define my own function (and learning to do this way) and use applymap to dataframe

no success so far.

```
Age
69
49
NaN
54
NaN
```

I've tried

```
   def get_rid_of_nulls(value):
     if value == np.nan:
        return 'Is Null value'
     else:
        return value
```

with this not working either

```
 if value == None
   if value isnull
   if value == np.na
   if value ==''
   if value == NaN
   if value == 'NaN'
```

None of the comparisons seems to work. I'm wrong for sure but I'm stuck and I'm very stubborn to use fillna

thanks

Comment: Nothing is equal to `nan`, not even `nan` itself. You need to use a special function to check whether a value is `nan`, you can't use `==`.

Comment: use `pd.isnull(value)` in your func

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As there is "replacing" in your title, and you mentioned `fillna` but not the `replace()` method, you can also obtain the same result doing something like that :

```
df.Age.replace(np.NaN, 'Is Null value', inplace=True)

# Or, depending on your needs:
df['Age'] = df.Age.replace(np.NaN, 'Is Null value')

# Or without `replace` :
df['Age'] = df.Age.apply(lambda x: x if not pd.isnull(x) else 'Is Null value')
```

Comment: No this won't work `NaN` intrinsically cannot be tested for value equality, only your last code snippet will work

Comment: OK, my bad was passing string 'np.NaN' which is not the same

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.isnull()`:

```
In [4]:
def get_rid_of_nulls(value):
    if pd.isnull(value):
        return 'Is Null value'
    else:
        return value

df['Age'].apply(get_rid_of_nulls)

Out[4]:
0               69
1               49
2    Is Null value
3               54
4    Is Null value
Name: Age, dtype: object
```

Similarly you can use the property that `NaN` does not equal itself:

```
In [5]:
def get_rid_of_nulls(value):
    if value != value:
        return 'Is Null value'
    else:
        return value

df['Age'].apply(get_rid_of_nulls)

Out[5]:
0               69
1               49
2    Is Null value
3               54
4    Is Null value
Name: Age, dtype: object
```

Comment: this is the entire point of .fillna - using .apply this way (with an embedded isnull check is completely non performant) and much more code

Comment: @jeff the op knows about fillna, and this approach is dumb I agree . I'm assuming the op just wanted to know why their approach didn't work as opposed to seeking the most performant method

Comment: ok sure - always like to point out that apply is the last tool to go to